# Aws console vpc id does not match aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-cli

When I log into my aws console I see the vpc id as "vpc-6856c210" however on my server through the aws cli I see "vpc-82fe07e9"

When I try to run a terraform script I get an error if i use 'vpc-6856c210' saying the VPC does not exist.

If I run the script using the 'vpc-82fe07e9' id it will run and I can see the instances in the cli however not the console.

Shouldn't they match? I am new to AWS and on the free tier

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Your cli is set to a **different region** than the console. Make sure that the console shows *Ohio* (aka `us-east-2`) in the top-right corner and also run the cli as `aws --region us-east-2 ec2 ...` to make it explicit.
2. Your cli credentials are for a **different account**. Try `aws sts get-caller-identity` and make sure that the output is what you expect, you can check that the account number there matches the one is console.

Hope that helps :)